# How does Orthogonality and Orthonormality relate to each other?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given the following questions:

> If $Q1$ and $Q2$ are orthogonal matrices, show that their product $Q1Q2$ is also an orthogonal matrix. Remember that orthogonal matrices are square matrices whose columns are orthonormal.

How does knowing that the columns of orthogonal matrices are orthonormal helps me show what is being asked? I really don't understand the difference between one and the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'relation' might be that, as the hint says, an orthogonal matrix has orthonormal columns, meaning that all of its columns have unit norm, and that if you take any two columns of the matrix and compute its dot product, the result will be zero.

It might help if you want to prove it 'algebraically', I guess, but, since $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are both orthogonal, we know that $Q_i^{T}Q_i = I$ for $i \in[1,2]$, so, $(Q_1Q_2)^{T}(Q_1Q_2) = Q_2^{T}Q_1^{T}Q_1Q_2 = Q_2^{T}(I)Q_2 = Q_2^{T}Q_2 = I$, hence the matrix $Q_1Q_2$ satisfies the condition for being orthogonal as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are several (equivalent, of course) ways to define "orthogonal matrix".  The hint is suggesting that you answer the question by showing that the columns of $Q_1 Q_2$ are orthonormal vectors.  So: what is the dot product of the $i$'th column of $Q_1 Q_2$ and the $j$'th column?